# Unnecessary/Ghost padding getting added on transform=rotate ()

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

When rotating the `table` and the `td` element, an unknown padding is added which I am unable to remove. The box model doesn't show any padding. Please help me in fixing it.

Below is my code which is causing unknown padding on rotation

```css
table {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  direction: rtl;
  height: 400px;
}

.peopleNames {
  width: 400px;
}

.peopleNames h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.innerDiv th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 50px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="peopleNames">
  <h2>Folow the data to know the requirement</h2>
  <div class='innerDiv'>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <h1>1</h1>
          </th>
          <th>
            <h1>2</h1>
          </th>
          <th>
            <h1>3</h1>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Jill do the work within given time</td>
          <td>Smith is the best </td>
          <td>50min is all you got</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button>Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the result you are expecting? Also, do you have control over the HTML? Because right now you rotating things twice just to leave them looking "the same way", it would be better generate the table the way you want to do it directly.

Comment: I am begginer in html,I just want to reuse the table that you get without any rotation

Comment: If it is the top padding you are talking about, they are the extra column width before rotation.

Comment: It is the padding in td element in tbody....there is top and bottom padding getting added to it.

Comment: What is a solution mean to you? Do you want to keep the rotate approach? Currently the table first turn each cell 90deg then table turn the itself 270deg to counter-rotate so it makes the text facing the correct direction, and it is unnecessary to me. Or you don't care, you just want a table to show the information with no 'extra padding'?

Comment: The table that I have without rotations,I want to turn it and look the way it looks with rotation in the most efficient way.....I am reusing the table without rotations,reason why all the mess I guess...

Comment: My approach is that the table is first rotated in anticlockwise direction and then the td element is rotated to rotate the text....inshort the th and tbody are being made 2 columns

Comment: I want to remove the padding caused by td element in tbody if possible in the most efficient way,I don't want to reuse the table that is there for vertical setup and transform it to make it work for horizontal setup also.i hope I am clear.

Comment: @Mr. Brickowski any fix for the problem?